# Выполнение ShellExecute на сервере

Tags: c++

Существует один локальный файловый сервер, на котором лежит исполняемый файл, доступ на сервер безпарольный.Отдебажить не могу из-за небольших познаний в с++.

```
ShellExecute(null, "open", "\\192.168.10.2\\файлы\\Дистрибутив\\Базы данных\\SQLServer.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

В случае если файл на компе находится, то все работает нормально
Проблема - просто не работает.

Comment: В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNC должен начинаться с четырех слешей (два слопает компилятор, два останется ОС)